# Mono.onErrorResume() doesn't always work as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, project-reactor

I'm not sure whether there is something wrong with my code or is it a bug in the reactor-core.
What i'm trying to do is to handle errors such as OptimisticLockingFailureException that happens when different threads are trying to save the same database record/entity at the same moment.

the example below is just a simpler form of what i have in the code and assuming that i have a main stream that contains a lot of operations and a sub-stream with the issue i have that should be executing some database calls using reactive mongo which is represented here with "processFlux()" method.

I'm applying a retry using onErrorResume() to call the same method from inside the "errorFallBack()" and my code goes like this:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;


public class TestClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.range(1,10)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .publish(integerFlux -> processFlux(integerFlux))
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> System.out.println("on error continue!!!"))
                .subscribe(x -> sleepMillis(100));
    }

    private static void sleepMillis(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Flux<Integer> processFlux(Flux<Integer> input) {
        return input
                .map(integer -> {
                    if (integer == 5)
                        throw new NumberFormatException();
                    return integer;
                })
                .onErrorResume(NumberFormatException.class, e -> errorFallBack(input));
    }

    private static Flux<Integer> errorFallBack(Flux<Integer> input) {
        return input
                .doOnNext(integer -> System.out.println("inside errorFallBack()"))
                .flatMap(integer -> processFlux(Flux.just(integer)));
    }
}
```

in the "processFlux()" method i assume there will be an exception thrown at some point of time and i try to catch it with the "onErrorResume()".

Since i'm using "publish()" in the main stream to wrap around "processFlux()" i expect that when the error happens the "onErrorResume()" is the one that will be called...the actual behaviour is that the "onErrorContinue()" of the min stream is the one that is being called.

is this a bug? or shall i change something in my code?

I'm using reactive mongo with spring boot 2.1.13.RELEASE,
spring cloud version Greenwich.SR5
and reactor-core version 3.3.6.RELEASE

Comment: have you debugged your code to verify your assumptions are correct?

Comment: I did debug and i have a unit test that verifies the code working, the issue happens on production :'(

Comment: yes, so the code doesn't work. did you take synchronization, threading, ... into account when writing your tests?

Comment: I did created another test (e2e) to flood the stream with messages for the same record id and i was able to see the correct behaviour sometimes  by seeing the correct log "Reloaded entity for immediate retry!" but some other times i see the OptimisticLockingFailureException thrown without any retries which made me think there is something wrong with the onErrorResume() operator of Mono.

Comment: @AhmedAli It's going to be incredibly difficult for anyone to answer this at present when we can't recreate it - can you post a [mcve] with the test that fails so we can attempt recreate it on our end? (If it's a bug in reactor that can be demonstrated then the reactor team are usually very quick to respond and put a fix in place.)

Comment: Thx @MichaelBerry, i updated the post and hope it's clearer now.